# How to include code excerpts using tags in asciidoc?

Tags: documentation, literate-programming, asciidoc

I can include the full `Greet.java` file

```
public class Greet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

from within the asciidoc file

```
== Hello Java
This is how one greets in Java:

[source,java]
.Greet.java
----
include::Greet.java
----
```

producing the documentation

[image: adocked-greet-java1.png]

But suppose that I only want to include an excerpt from the code delimited by tags. In the code above, suppose I only want to include the `main` function.

I don't see symbolic tags in the [documentation](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/), but [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2014/04/awesome-asciidoc-include-partial-parts.html) page suggests that it's sufficient to write

```
public class Greet {
    // tag::helloMethod[]
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
    // end::helloMethod[]
}
```

and

```
== Hello Java
This is how one greets in Java:

[source,java]
.Greet.java
----
include::Greet.java[tags=helloMethod]
----
```

That just produces:

[image: adocked-greet-java2.png]

Can you suggest a method that would include just the excerpt? I'm using asciidoc 8.6.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing should work fine in [Asciidoctor](https://asciidoctor.org/) (the [Ruby implementation of AsciiDoc](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/what-is-asciidoctor/)), but not [AsciiDoc](https://asciidoc.org/) ([the Python implementation](https://pypi.org/project/asciidoc3/)).

Notice though the different mechanism for obtaining syntax highlighting.

To get syntax highlighting with asciidoc one uses a command-line switch `asciidoc -a source-highlighter=pygments file.adoc`.

No command-line switch is needed (or possible) with Asciidoctor. With AsciiDoctor syntax highlighting is obtained by:

1. Inserting `:source-highlighter: pygments` at the top of each source file, and
2. Running `sudo gem install pygments.rb` to install **pygments**.

Answer (score 0):

The Asciidoctor `tags` option can include multiple tags as well;

```
[tags="tag 1, tag 2, …"]
```

Bringing in more code excerpts in one go…